# How to make makefile call the proper version of docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, makefile

I have a makefile that calls `docker-compose` multiple times. However, my own machine has `docker compose` (the newer plugin version). Most teammates have the other one.

Is there a way to somehow make the Makefile call one or the other, depending on availability?

I can get this working:

```
ifneq ($(shell docker compose version 2>/dev/null),)
  DOCKER_COMPOSE=docker compose
else
  DOCKER_COMPOSE=docker-compose
endif
```

But how do I now call that?

Answer (score 1):

Add a target in your makefile that references the var you set above.  For example,

```
composeup:
    $(DOCKER_COMPOSE) up
```